# how to find two max numbers ( negative and positive ) in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for best solution to solve this problem

Problem:
Create a function named ArrayChallenge (Javascript)  which accepts a single argument "arr" which is an array of numbers. This function will return the string true if any two numbers can be multiplied so that the answer is greater than double the sum of all the elements in the array. If not, return the string false.

For example:
if the argument "arr" is [2, 5, 6, -6, 16, 2, 3, 6, 5, 3] then the sum of all these elements is 42, and doubling it is 84. There are two elements in "arr", 16 * 6 = 96 where 96 is greater than 84, so your program should return the string true. An example of an "arr" that should return false is [1, 2, 4] since double its sum (14) is larger than multiplying its two largest elements (4 * 2 = 8).

my solution was

```js
function ArrayChallenge(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) return 'false'

  let maxNeg = 0
  let neg = 0

  let pos = 0
  let maxPos = 0

  const sum = arr.reduce((total, num) => {
    if (num < 0) {
      if (num < neg) maxNeg = num
      else neg = num
    } else {
      if (num >= maxPos) {
        pos = maxPos
        maxPos = num
      } else if (num > pos) pos = num
    }

    return total + num
  }, 0)

  if (maxPos * pos > sum * 2 || maxNeg * neg > sum * 2) return 'true'
  else return 'false'
}
```

https://codepen.io/hamodey85/pen/ExmrdgM

Comment: Just find the 2 largest elements, multiply them, and see if it's larger than double the sum. If there are at least 2 negative numbers, do the same thing with the 2 smallest numbers.

Comment: I feel like this may apply here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you need to understand the fact that if the highest possible product of the 2 numbers in the array are not greater than the twice sum of the array then there are no possible pairs available.

**Steps to solve the problem**

**step 1**
precompute the sum of the array.(can be easily done using for loop or reduce function)

**step 2**
get the 2 maximum values from the array(depending on allowed complexity you can either sort the array and get it i.e.O(nlogn) or traverse the array twice i.e.O(2n) which is better.

**step 3**
compare product of the 2 maximum and precomputed sum and return true if product is greater than the precomputed sum

*Sorting Apprach*

```
function ArrayChallenge(arr){  
  var precomputedSum = arr.reduce((a,c) => a+c,0); //Step 1   
  var sortedArray = arr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});// Step 2 
  var product = sortedArray[0] * sortedArray[1];//part of step 2  
  return product > 2*precomputedSum ;
}
```

*looping approach*

```
function ArrayChallenge(arr){  
  var precomputedSum = arr.reduce((a,c) => a+c,0); //Step 1   
  int firstMax = -2147483648;// Step 2
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]>firstMax)firstMax=arr[i];//step 2
  } 
   int secondMax = -2147483648;// Step 2
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]>secondMax && arr[i]!=firstMax)secondMax=arr[i];//step 2
  } 
  var product = firstMax * secondMax;//part of step 2  
  return product > 2*precomputedSum ;
}
```

Comment: If there are 2 negative numbers in the array, multiplying them together will be a positive number, and that could be higher than the sum*2.

Answer (score 0):

so I tried to solve it in several way but I found this better solution so far

```js
function ArrayChallenge(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) return 'false'

  let maxNeg = 0
  let neg = 0

  let pos = 0
  let maxPos = 0

  const sum = arr.reduce((total, num) => {
    if (num < 0) {
      if (num < neg) maxNeg = num
      else neg = num
    } else {
      if (num >= maxPos) {
        pos = maxPos
        maxPos = num
      } else if (num > pos) pos = num
    }

    return total + num
  }, 0)

  if (maxPos * pos > sum * 2 || maxNeg * neg > sum * 2) return 'true'
  else return 'false'
}
```